# Checkbox not getting values correctly

Tags: php, checkbox

I am doing a baseball quiz and one of the questions requires the use of checkboxes since it has multiple answers. The question is irrelevant but here is what I have for the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 1" value="Player 1" />Player 1
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 2" value="Player 2" />Player 2
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 3" value="Player 3" />Player 3
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 4" value="Player 4" />Player 4
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 5" value="Player 5" />Player 5
<input type="checkbox" name="Player 6" value="Player 6" />Player 6
```

Let's say the correct answer is Players 2, 3, and 6. Here is what I am doing:

```
if(isset($_POST['Player 2']) && isset($_POST['Player 3']) && isset($_POST['Player 6'])) {    // Check if 2, 3, and 6 are checked
   print "<p>Your answer is correct!</p>";
   $correct++;
} else {
   print "<p>Your answer is incorrect.</p>";
}
```

I tried testing this by selected Players 2, 3, and 6 which are the right answers, but my program still said my answer was incorrect. I tried putting in debugging statements to see if the values are being stored correctly and they are not. For instance when I tried to say:

```
if(isset($_POST['Player 2'])) {
   $p2 = $_POST['Player 2'];
}
.....
print "<p>The answer is " . $p2 . ".</p>";
```

It would print the string "The answer is ." which means its not getting the value at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do a var_dump on $_POST. Is the form being submitted via POST?

Comment: Use `Player_1` or `Player1`

Comment: I think it is being submitted via POST. How can I check in case? Where would I put `var_dump`? At the beginning of the `process_form()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send form via POST method not GET. Try to dump values with:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: "Make sure you send form via POST..." Is that what this line does? `<form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">`? If not, how would I make sure I am doing that?

Comment: Yes. That's the line and it seems correct. Avoid spaces in name property. Use "Player1" instead of "Player 1".

Answer (score 0):

“Player 1” as name attribute is valid HTML, but PHP converts spaces in underscores for variable names from HTML Forms.

So you have to check for `Player_1` instead of `Player 1` or, better, to rename your checkbox to `Player1`.

From [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example <input name="a.b" /> becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I changed the `name` field for all of them to no spaces and it works properly now! Thank you.